# Pass argument using Client Side in Telerik MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, telerik-mvc

I'm developing some application using Telerik MVC.I wanted to pass Argument from client side.Is there any way to do it?

Here is my code for rad window

```
@{ Html.Telerik().Window()
    .Name("NewsWindow")
    .Title("Edit Here")
    .Draggable(true)
    .Scrollable(true)
    .Resizable(resizing => resizing
    .Enabled(true))
    .LoadContentFrom("News/NewsEditor")
    .Modal(true)
    .Buttons(b => b.Refresh().Close())
    .Width(600)
    .Height(650)
    .Visible(false)
    .Render();
```

}

Comment: u can use ajax request

Answer (score 2):

Remove

```
.LoadContentFrom("News/NewsEditor")
```

Add a function containing below codes and bind it to your desired event.

```
$("#NewsWindow")
    .data("kendoWindow")
    .refresh({
        url: baseURL + "News/NewsEditor",
        data: { argumentName: argumentValue }
    })
    .open();
```

Comment: If it helps, mark as an answer. @jehan-perera